# Calculate sum squares within treatment

Tags: anova, excel

I have a group of subjects treated with a drug formulation and a parameter is measured. The next week (period 2) same group of subjects is treated with the same drug formulation and the same parameter is measured.  So for each subject we have two values for each of the treatments at Period 1 and 2.  How to calculate the variance within treatment (sigma wt 2) parameter from measurements of the clinical parameter on both periods.  I want to do it in Excel so I learn the steps.